# vulkan build error : 'createResultValue' is not a member of 'vk'

Tags: compiling, c++, vulkan

I'm trying to compile a program that uses vulkan hpp and it uses a method in a file named vulkan_driver.h like this:

```
// Evaluate f and if result is not a success throw proper vk exception.
#define CHECK_VK_RESULT(x) do { \
   vk::Result res = vk::Result(x); \
   int tmp = 0; \
   vk::createResultValue(res, tmp, __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)); \
} while (0)
```

when i compile i get the following error:

```
[  199s] In file included from /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/decaf-emu-20220508T212126/src/libgpu/src/vulkan/vulkan_driver.cpp:2:
[  199s] /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/decaf-emu-20220508T212126/src/libgpu/src/vulkan/vulkan_driver.cpp: In member function 'void vulkan::Driver::initialise(vk::Instance, vk::PhysicalDevice, vk::Device, vk::Queue, uint32_t)':
[  199s] /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/decaf-emu-20220508T212126/src/libgpu/src/vulkan/vulkan_driver.h:36:8: error: 'createResultValue' is not a member of 'vk'; did you mean 'createResultValueType'?
[  199s]    36 |    vk::createResultValue(res, tmp, __FILE__ ":" TOSTRING(__LINE__)); \
[  199s]       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[  199s] /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/decaf-emu-20220508T212126/src/libgpu/src/vulkan/vulkan_driver.cpp:89:4: note: in expansion of macro 'CHECK_VK_RESULT'
[  199s]    89 |    CHECK_VK_RESULT(vmaCreateAllocator(&allocatorCreateInfo, &mAllocator));
[  199s]       |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[  199s] make[2]: *** [src/libgpu/CMakeFiles/libgpu.dir/build.make:647: src/libgpu/CMakeFiles/libgpu.dir/src/vulkan/vulkan_driver.cpp.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same error while trying to build https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan (on Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10)
For example [this line in glfw.cpp](https://github.com/jherico/Vulkan/blob/58aa93f91cff6f450dcc0911ac97c777e1557d88/base/glfw/glfw.cpp#L32) leads to the same compile error as Ahmed Moselhi had posted.

I found that the name AND signature for this function has been changed in vulkan.hpp
(see [this commit in the Github Vulkan-Headers repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers/commit/8ba8294c86d0e99fcb457bedbd573dd678ccc9b3#diff-a83f956c7aeb2b6dee7ffa2f249c0d98a2cfad6e157fe8438e372a5267afaeffL5986-R6086))

To get the compile working again, I needed to change the usages of the function from:

```
vk::createResultValue(result, rawSurface, "vk::CommandBuffer::begin");
```

to:

```
vk::createResultValueType(result, rawSurface);
```

In your case @Ahmed Moselhi, you should change the code to the following:

```
vk::createResultValueType(res, tmp);
```